# Athena unnest json array of string within another json array of structs

Tags: json, presto, amazon-athena

I have the following AWS Athena create table statement:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS s2cs3dataset.s2c_storage (
         `MessageHeader` string,
         `TimeToProcess` float,
         `KeyCreated` string,
         `KeyLastTouch` string,
         `CreatedDateTime` string,
         `TableReference` array<struct<`BusinessObject`: string,
         `TransactionType`: string,
         `ReferenceKeyId`: float,
         `ReferencePrimaryKey`: string,
         `IncludedTables`: array<string>>>,
         `SAPStoreReference` string 
) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
         'serialization.format' = '1' ) LOCATION 's3://api-dev-dpstorage-s3/S2C_INPUT/storage/' TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false');
```

From this, I want to select the following items with this query:

```
SELECT MessageHeader,
TimeToProcess,
KeyCreated,
KeyLastTouch,
CreatedDateTime,
tr.BusinessObject, 
tr.TransactionType,
tr.ReferencePrimaryKey,
it.IncludedTables,
SAPStoreReference
FROM s2c_storage
cross join UNNEST(s2c_storage.tablereference) as p(tr)
cross join UNNEST(tr.IncludedTables) as p(it)
```

However I get the following error:

> SYNTAX_ERROR: line 9:1: Expression "it" is not of type ROW

If I remove the bottom cross join and the column that references it, the query works fine, so there's something I'm doing wrong in trying to unpack the JSON data for the array of string within the array of struct. Any tips?

Comment: What's the output of `SELECT typeof(tr.IncludedTables), tr.IncludedTables FROM s2c_storage CROSS JOIN UNNEST(s2c_storage.tablereference) AS p(tr) LIMIT 1`?

Comment: _col0                includedtables
array(varchar)        [PLU]

Comment: If `tr.IncludedTables` is `array(varchar)` then, after `UNNEST(tr.IncludedTables) as p(it)`, `it` is `varchar`. Replace `it.IncludedTables` with `it` in your query -- does that help?

Comment: That worked Piotr. can you assist me to understand why it worked/helped?

Comment: I added some explanation as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per clarifying comments, `tr.IncludedTables` is of type `array(varchar)`.
Thus, in the query `... CROSS JOIN UNNEST(tr.IncludedTables) AS p(it)`, the type of `it` is `varchar`. In the select clause, you can refer to this value as `it` (or, giving an alias: `it as IncludedTables`), but you cannot refer to it with `it.IncludedTables` (`varchar` value has no "fields", so in particular it has no `IncludedTables` field).